# react-hook-form is leaving the input field while typing with mode property set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form` **V7** with `Material UI` to create a simple form however, there is a weird behavior when setting the mode in `useForm({mode: ".."})`
Here is my code snippet:

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { Button, Grid, Link, TextField, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { _MESSAGES } from "src/constants/messages";
import * as yup from "yup";
import AuthContainer from "./AuthContainer";

// #####################   Helpers    ######################
/**
 * @param {object} error
 * @param {string} msg
 */
const renderError = (error, msg) =>
  error ? <Alert severity="error">{msg}</Alert> : "";

// ##############   Schema & Default Values   ##############
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
});

const defaultValues = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

// ######################   Styles    ######################
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

// #################   Main Component    ###################
const SignInPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    control,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    // Reset form fields
    reset();
  };

  console.log(errors);

  const Form = () => (
    <>
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        Sign In
      </Typography>
      <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
              autoComplete="email"
              label="Email Address"
              {...field}
              error={errors.email?.message ? true : false}
            />
          )}
        />
        {renderError(errors.email?.message, _MESSAGES.required)}
        <Controller
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
              autoComplete="current-password"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              {...field}
              error={errors.password?.message ? true : false}
            />
          )}
        />
        {renderError(errors.password?.message, _MESSAGES.required)}
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.submit}
        >
          Sign In
        </Button>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
              Forgot password?
            </Link>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Link href="#" variant="body2" color="secondary">
              {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
            </Link>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </>
  );

  return <AuthContainer Form={<Form />} />;
};

export default SignInPage;
```

> What might have gone wrong?

Here is a Gif of what happened:

1. selected the input field
2. started typing
3. after one char it leaves the input field so, I need to select it to type again.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `Form` component to its own Component, otherwise, you are mount and unmount your `Form` Component each re-render.

```
const App = () => {
  const Form = () => {} // mount and unmount with each re-render
  return <div><Form /></div>
}
```

to

```
const Form = () => {}

const App = () => {
  return <div><Form /></div>
}
```

Comment: Can I ask, why is it unmounting the form?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass down the `ref`. For MUI TextField should do the following:

```
<Controller
  control={methods.control}
  name="fieldName"
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <TextField {...field} inputRef={ref} /> // ⬅️ The ref
  )}
/>
```

A working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-microservice-xpuru

Does it work now ?

Comment: Nope, the `ref` is already assigned by `{...field}`

Comment: Yes but it's the wrong ref prop.

You should use `inputRef` prop of TextField and not `ref`.
https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries

Comment: See this example from the official website: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs

Comment: So, when `useForm({ mode: "..." })` is not set there is no problem, I can get all data of the form, however, when this property is set I am facing some weird behaviors "leaving the input while typing".

Comment: You right, that's strange, I copy/paste your code and it's working: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-textfield-forked-1w8r6

Comment: Yep, working in Sandbox, however, not working locally.

Comment: Which version of React Hook Form are you using ?
In your case, do the inputs work without React Hook Form ?

Comment: Updated the post, it is V7